# Select users with more than one instance in database

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table with a userID field and an itemID field. I would like to select all of those users that have two or more instances where itemID is the same (that is, if for example there are 3 records where userID = 1 and itemID = 7 then I would like those results, but not if there's just one instance). I need to get all users (not just results for a certain userID).
Can anybody suggest how I could do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use group by and having. The having clause is like where except that it also works on aggregations. So it's something like `select userID, itemID, count(*) from mytable group by userID, itemID having count(*) > 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using aggregation and a `having` clause.  If you just want the users:

```
select distinct userID
from t
group by userId, itemID
having count(*) >= 2;
```

This is an interesting query because it is one of the very rare situations where `group by` and `select distinct` are used together.  If you wanted the `userId`/`itemId` pairs, then you would use `select userId, itemId`, without the `distinct`.